# MEAN stack, net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error

Tags: mean-stack

I'm following this MEAN stack tutorial.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OhPFgqHz68o

Upon starting up the grunt server, the browser is automatically directed to this address:

http://localhost:9000/#/movies

and I get the following error in Chrome:

> GET http://localhost:3000/movie net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

In Firefox the error says:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at http://localhost:3000/movie. (Reason: CORS
>   request failed).

I'm not sure why the error is referring to port 3000. The url is localhost:9000

I have no idea what to do to get rid of this error.

Comment: Is your mongodb service (mongod) running and listening on the port that your application is trying to connect to it at?

Answer (score 0):

The firefox error comes up because angular sends an OPTION request. You have to allow the `OPTION` request method to your server (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Overview):
change in your `index.js`

```
resp.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
```

to

```
resp.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
```